# How to define variable in Firefox add-on that can be accessible from page javascript

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I need to access page response headers from its javascript. So I want to use extension that reads response headers and places it to variable that can be accessed from page's JS. I think I can use some existed extension but I don't understand how to make captured headers accessible from page's JS. window.varName='something', varName='something' don't work for me. Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: unsafeWindow also doesn't work

Comment: Are you trying to access the response header from your content script and afterwards pass this to your main JS file?

Comment: Yes. I figured out that only way to get response headers without aditional AJAX request is using add-on.

Comment: What you need to do is send that info from content script to parent script. Are you using sdk or classic bootstrap?